# Justifying a certain application of Lebesgue Dominated Convergence

Tags: measure-theory

In a proof I'm reading, I came across the following application of Lebesgue Dominated Convergence. We let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space, $f\in C(X)$, $T:X\to X$ continuous, and $h\in L^1(X,\mathcal B,\mu)$, where $\mathcal B$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra corresponding to $d$, and $\mu$ is  some probability measure. Then it was established that $\mu$-a.e. $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(T^ix)h(x)=h(x)\int_Xf(y)d\mu(y),$$ and it is stated that by Dominated convergence we then have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\int_Xf(T^ix)h(x)d\mu(x)=\int_Xh(x)d\mu(x)\int_Xf(y)d\mu(y).$$

To apply Dominated convergence, we need a.e. pointwise convergence, which is clear by the first display, and we need an integrable dominating function. Since $h\in L^1(X,\mathcal B,\mu)$, it seems that the first display also gives a dominating function, *if* we can show that the convergence $\frac1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(T^ix)\to\int fd\mu$ is uniform. Else, I don't see what the dominating function should look like. The problem is that we need to somehow bound $\frac1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(T^ix)$ a.e. by a constant, uniformly for all $n$.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous and $X$ is compact, there exists $M$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M$ for every $x \in X$. In particular, for every $x \in X$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$,
$$\left|\frac1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(T^ix)\right| \leq \frac1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} M = M$$

Comment: I can't see how I overlooked this... Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome !